# Split a string into sub-strings starting from " ] " ending with "As"

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, reactjs

I have extracted a string from stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2,
using this query: 
`EXEC sp_helptext 'MyStoredProcedureName';` I need to split this string into arrays or sub strings starting from the ending parenthesize " ] " and ending with the word "As".
I have to save ALL fields starting with "@" in (fieldsArray) and the types of these fields -After the space- in (typeArray) and then output them to a file in **node.js** with this format:

```
 InvoiceNo: {
     type: DataType.String(255),
    },
```

Here is the extracted string:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedureName]
 @InvoiceNo int
,@TransDate datetime 
,@CustomerID bigint
,@CurrencyID bigint
,@SalesInvoiceTypeID bigint 
,@DiscountAmount nvarchar(50) 
,@DetailXml ntext 
,@TotalAll float 
,@TotalBefore float 
,@TaxAmount float
,@OtherExpenses float
,@OutVouchersNo nvarchar(1000)
,@Notes nvarchar(1000) 
,@TotalWiegts float
,@VoucherDefID bigint
,@SalesmanID bigint
,@IsSale bit

 AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

**Edit:** I used another query instead of the mentioned above. Now I have an object containing the result of the query which is the Names of the fields each in separate line. What I need to do now is to separate this object to a string array so that I can deal with each name separately.
the object "Names" contain the result of the query that I used:

```
Names = await sequelize.query(namesQuery);
```

And this is the output of `console.log(Names);`

```
[ [ { '': 'InvoiceNo' },
    { '': 'TransDate' },
    { '': 'CustomerID' },
    { '': 'CurrencyID' },
    { '': 'SalesInvoiceTypeID' },
    { '': 'DiscountAmount' },
```

I tried `Names.split` but I got the error "Names.split is not a function"

Comment: Have you considered querying the `sys.parameters` table instead?

Comment: @R.Richards Nop! please explain to me more

Comment: @AreejQadomi see my answer posted before R.Richards added his comment.

Comment: @SteveFord  please see the Edit of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the `Sys.Parameters` table instead:

```
SELECT Substring(Parameters.Name,2,255) + ': { type: DataType.' + 
       CASE types.Name
          WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'String(' + CAST(Parameters.Max_Length As Varchar)      
          WHEN 'int' THEN 'Int'
          ELSE 'COMPLETE THE REST OF THIS yourself.....'
       END + '),},'
FROM Sys.Parameters
INNER JOIN sys.procedures on parameters.object_id = procedures.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.types on parameters.system_type_id = types.system_type_id AND parameters.user_type_id = types.user_type_id
Where procedures.name = 'MyStoredProcedureName'
```

Comment: Unable to execute the query. what are " etc."  and " END + '),},' " ? it object on them. please explain to me what this query do ?

Comment: @AreejQadomi etc. means that you have to fill out the rest of the details, you will need to add a WHEN for every type that you expect e.g. INT ot DOUBLE etc. I've updated it so it should run, but you will have to make sure that the CASE statement reflects all of the types you expect.

Comment: It works ! thank you , I checked your answer :) @steve

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that the symbol `@` is only used to identify the beginning of a field name, you can use regular expressions as follows:

```
let result = {}

str.match(/@\w+ [a-z]+/g)
  .map(s => s.match(/@(\w+) ([a-z]+)/))
  .forEach(r => {
    let fieldName = r[1]
    let type = r[2]
    result[fieldName] = { type }
  })

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2))
```

This will output

```
{
  "InvoiceNo": {
    "type": "int"
  },
  "TransDate": {
    "type": "datetime"
  },
  ...
}
```

I guess the same could be achieved with only regex, but the code is easier to understand this way:

- the first `match` captures all the `@FieldName type` strings
- the second `match` captures for each of these `FieldName` and `type`
- the last one fills the object `result` with members of name `FieldName` and content `{ type: "type" }`
- the last command formats everything and outputs to the console

Comment: Edit: @Antoine I want something else now if you could help, each field now in a separate line and not preceded by @ , what should I edit on your code to get the same format ?

Comment: Do you have a sample ?

Comment: Yes, please see the Edit of the question